# Set up access control to allow non-registered members to see intro text, but not full text

Tags: joomla, acl, membership, joomla3.0

I need to set up ACL permissions on a web site I am developing such that guests can see the intro-text of an article, but cannot see the full-text unless they are registered.

The site is using Joomla 3.0.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to the Administrator back-end.

1. Go to Content > Article Manager and edit the article(s).
2. Set the Access Level (Details right side of editor) for the article with Read More link to Registered.
3. Click the tab Article options and find the "Show unauthorized links". Select Yes.
4. Save and close.
5. In the same window click the Options button from the top toolbar.
6. Set the Show Unauthorized Links to Yes and Save the settings. This is a global setting and will apply to all published articles that have the read more link and registered+ access.